# Zeta function ratio

Tags: prime-numbers, riemann-zeta, zeta-functions

Let's the zeta function is defined as
$$
\zeta(s)= \prod_p (1-p^{-s})^{-1}=\prod_p \frac{1}{(1-p^{-s})}
$$
so for a negative therm should be
$$
\zeta(-s)= \prod_p (1-p^{s})^{-1}=\prod_p \frac{1}{(1-p^{s})}
$$
for the Euler product where $p$ is prime and the product is over all the primes.
I can say that the productorial therm could be rewritten as:
$$
(1-p^{-s})=(1-\frac{1}{p^s})=(\frac{p^s-1}{p^s})=(\frac{1-p^s}{-p^s})
$$
So computing the ration between $\zeta(s)$ and $\zeta(-s)$ will result in

$$
\frac{\zeta(s)}{\zeta(-s)}=\frac{\prod_p (1-p^{s})}{\prod_p (1-p^{-s})}=\prod_p\frac{ (1-p^{s})}{ (1-p^{-s})} =\prod_p\frac{ (1-p^{s}) (-p^s)}{ (1-p^{s})}= \prod_p -p^s
$$

That is, the ratio of the zeta function with positive and negative argument $s$ should be equal to the negated complex power $s$ of all the primes.

This is a weird result, but I cannot understand what's wrong in here and especially the meaning of this result.

Sorry for the newbie (mathematical) question.

Comment: The product over the primes converges only for $s>1$ so your relation $\zeta(-s)=\prod_p\frac{1}{(1-p^s)}$ is not true (in fact the initial relation is valid only for $s>1$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The analytic continuation of $\zeta(s)$ Dirichlet series and Euler product is exactly the same idea as for the geometric series $$\frac1{1-z}=\sum_{n\ge 0} z^n$$ which is valid only for $|z|<1$.

Your same reasonning would lead to

$$0=\frac1{1-5}+\frac18\frac{1}{1-1/2}= \sum_{n\ge 0} (5^n+\frac18 (1/2)^n)$$
which is obviously wrong.